# regex to filter positive and negative numbers

Tags: php, regex

I use the following function to filter numbers from a string (including some special cases such as prices (starting with $)):

```
function _process_numbers($string) {
return preg_replace(
   '/(?<!\{)         # Assert no preceding {
    (?<![^\s$-])     # Assert no preceding non-whitespace except $-
    \b               # Match start of number
    (\d+(?:\.\d+)?+) # Match number (optional decimal part)
    \b               # Match end of number
    (?![^{}]*\})     # Assert that next brace is not a closing brace
    (?![^\s.!?,%])   # Assert no following non-whitespace except .!?,%
    /x', 
    '{NUMBER|\1}', $string
  );
}

echo _process_numbers("100.000.000 and -0.33 and $100.50 and 0.06%");
```

This works rather well, except that (1) the minus "-" should be included inside the braces of the output and (2) numbers up to 1 billion (and minus one billion) should be supported. In other words; the above returns as output:

```
{NUMBER|100.000}.000 and -{NUMBER|0.33} and ${NUMBER|100.50} and {NUMBER|0.06}%
```

But the expected output is:

```
{NUMBER|100.000} and {NUMBER|-0.33} and ${NUMBER|100.50} and {NUMBER|0.06}%
```

What should be changed?

Comment: `(\d+(?:\.\d+)?+)` must include the minus sign. It could also be that `\b` matches `-`.

Comment: I tried that, but the number then doesn't get matched. Also, the 100 million doesn;t get matched...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

should do the trick:

```
(-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?+) # Match number (optional decimal part)
```

**UPDATE**

remove the - from the look-behind assertion, capture the first (`\b` or `-`).

```
<?php

function _process_numbers($string) {
return preg_replace(
   '/(?<!\{)         # Assert no preceding {
    (?<![^\s$])     # Assert no preceding non-whitespace except $-
    (\b|-)               # Match start of number
    (\d+(?:\.\d+)*) # Match number (optional decimal part)
    \b               # Match end of number
    (?![^{}]*\})     # Assert that next brace is not a closing brace
    (?![^\s.!?,%])   # Assert no following non-whitespace except .!?,%
    /x', 
    '{NUMBER|\1\2}', $string
  );
}

echo _process_numbers("100.000.000 and -0.33 and $100.50 and 0.06%"), "\n";
```

Comment: It doesn't. The number doesn't get matched at all now :(

Comment: Thanks - it catches the negtive numbers beautifully, but not the 100.000.000 (output: {NUMBER|100.000}.000) Any idea as to why? This has been bothering me for some time...the max length of a number isn't specified in the regex?

Comment: yep… `(\d+(?:\.\d+)?+)` must be `(\d+(?:\.\d+)*)`